# Your magic is very sketchy

Tags: riddle, rhyme

## *Your magic is very sketchy...*

> When I'm put under pressure what was inside comes out
>
> The lower I fall the darker my snout
>
> I own a magic hat that makes things disappear
>
> As I shed my skin, abracadabra I reappear
>
> What am I?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Seems like you are:

> A **pencil**

---

Because,

*When I'm put under pressure my insides fall out*

> The graphite in the centre (insides) rubs off (falls out) on the page when you use pressure.

*The lower I fall the darker my snout*

> Not 100% sure about this one, but graphite is dark in colour and can smudge around the end of the pencil as you use it more (i.e. as the pencil gets shorter/lower).

*I own a magic hat that makes things disappear*

> Often pencils have an eraser on the end.

*As I shed my skin, abracadabra I reappear*

> Sharpening the pencil makes the graphite reappear.

---

And from the title:

> You use pencils to sketch pictures.

Comment: Huh. I thought it was Bug Bunny...

Comment: is the darker snout a reference to the H / B value ?

Comment: For the second line, I would infer that _rot13(n funec crapvy znxrf n zhpu yvtugre fgebxr, ohg n jbea qbja gvc yrnqf gb n guvpx qnex yvar)_

Answer (score 11):

Are you a :

> **volcano** ?

---

Because,

*When I'm put under pressure my insides fall out*

> Volcanos erupt lava when the pressure increases

*The lower I fall the darker my snout*

> The deeper the lava, the blacker the surrounding rocks of inactive volcanos.

*I own a magic hat that makes things disappear*

> Throw anything inside a volcano and its literally gone :D

*As I shed my skin, abracadabra I reappear*

> Lava keeps accumulating a black solid layer that is lost again and again

---

And from the title:

> The magic is sketchy since things that disappear by lava can't be brought back.

Comment: I'm guessing that @Alconja has the correct answer, but +1 for an excellently justified answer!